# Find duplicated combination of rows in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I got a 2D array like this:

```
row | user_id | risk_id | measure_id | description
---------------------------------------------------
 0  |    73   |    12   |     32     |    'foo'
 1  |    73   |    12   |     32     |    'bar'
 2  |    31   |    23   |     31     |   'foobar'
 3  |    31   |    23   |     31     |    'foo'
```

I want to check if the combination between user_id, risk_id and measure_id is unique, and if not return another 2D array with the rows being the user_id and the columns the row, like this

```
user_id | row_0 | row_1 | ......
--------------------------------
   73   |   0   |   1   | ......
   31   |   2   |   3   | ......
```

Comment: How did you get the information into the array is the data from a database?

Comment: no, the info comes from the view, and i'm going to save on the DB, the combination of the filds must be unique because they are the primary key on the table, but i want to notify the user in the view before the insert is done changing the color of the duplicated rows

Comment: Can you share what you have attempted so far?

Comment: foreach ($table as $row) {
      $combination['key'] = $r['rowId'];
      $combination['value'] = $r['userID'].$r['riskID'].$r['measureID'];
    }

Answer (score 0):

This is for finding duplicates, but will return rows, not columns:

```
 SELECT x.user_id, x.row
      FROM YOUR_TABLE x
      JOIN (SELECT t.user_id
        FROM YOUR_TABLE t
        GROUP BY t.user_id, risk_id, measure_id
        HAVING COUNT(t.user_id) > 1) y ON y.user_id= x.user_id;
```

This one will return a table grouped by `user_id`, and duplicated rows stored comma separated in column `rows`:

```
user_id  |  rows
72       | 0, 1
31       | 2, 3


SELECT x.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(x.row SEPARATOR ',') as rows
          FROM YOUR_TABLE x
          JOIN (SELECT t.user_id
            FROM YOUR_TABLE t
            GROUP BY t.user_id, risk_id, measure_id
            HAVING COUNT(t.user_id) > 1) y ON y.user_id= x.user_id
          GROUP BY x.user_id;
```

Comment: Im not retriving values from a database, im trying to prevent a DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX before inserting the data, to alert the user that they have a duplicate on the list